# Best practice to represent Money (value + currency) in Grails

Tags: grails, currency

I'm not much familiar to Java Currency type, and how it being used in Grails. Though, I'm yet to use it, I saw a tag `<g:currencySelect>` to use in the views. So, how do I represent it in the domain class.

```
class Money {
BigDecimal value
Currency currency
....
}
```

or is there a better sol, which compares diff money objects, format according to the locale ( ',' in EU for separator etc)

thanks in advance.
Babu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look a the [Currencies plugin](http://www.grails.org/Currencies%20plugin).  It provides a Money class for holding monetary amounts of differing currencies.  They can be embedded into domain classes like so:

```
class CustomerTransaction {
    Date date = new Date()
    Money amount

    static embedded = ['money']
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. How would a domain class using Money look and what's the underlying column type?

Comment: thanks for both your comments.. the currency plugin gave a idea about how to implement myself..

Comment: Don't use the currencies plugin. It is dead and broken.

Comment: It's no big deal to handle Currency in Grails domain classes yourself, Hibernate automatically saves the currency code (3 letters) as varchar.
You just have to help Grails UI by defining getter and setter with String values, because a constructor with String parameter doesn't exist:

class MyDomainObj {
    BigDecimal amount
    Currency currency
    
    static transient ['currencyCode']

 def setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
  currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
 }
 
 String getCurrencyCode() {
  return currency.getCurrencyCode()
 }
}

Use 'currencyCode' in your GSP.

Answer (score 2):

You should use BigDecimal.  Groovy and Grails has excellent native support for it as a datatype on GORM domain classes as well.  For reasoning behind using it, see here

[What is the best data type to use for money in java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use the JScience library. It's just a shame it's not in a Maven repo yet, and doesn't have a Groovy wrapper to make it Groovier (TM).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have also live exchage rates updates then following plugin could help  https://grails.org/ExchangeRates+Plugin all rates are pulled from Yahoo Finance.

Answer (score 0):

since the original answer seems to be outdated, you might want to take a look at the [money-plugin](https://github.com/ticketbis/grails-money) which is fresh and currently maintained.