# Grails Currencies Plugin: Unable to resolve class Money

Tags: grails-plugin, grails, grails-domain-class

I installed the grails currency plugin. I want to use the Money type in my grails domain class as such:

```
class FOO{
...
    Money lunchCost = new Money(amount:0.00, currency:'USD')
    Money dinnerCost = new Money(amount:0.00, currency:'USD')
...
}
```

I get an error when I compile saying "unable to resolve class Money". I traced the package heirchy of the Grails Money Plugin and tried to put in:

```
cr.co.arquetipos.currencies.Money breakfastCost = new cr.co.arquetipos.currencies.Money(amount:0.00, currency:'USD')
```

---- That didn't work either.

1) When I generated Foo, grails placed the domain class under "projectName.Foo" as it does for every domain class created. 
2) I'm using Grails 1.3.5.

Do you have any ideas as to where the Currencies class is so I can include it in the 
"import <....Money> and get rid of this compilation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here: The plugin does not integrate with the Grails project, at all. Nevertheless, it has been installed to `${user.home}/.grails/1.3.5/projects/${project.name}/plugins/currencies-0.3`.

Since the plugin has been last updated in 2008 and doesn't cover too much functionality, I'd suggest to just copy the two domain classes (in the `grails-app/domain` folder) into your project.

For an evaluation, you may also want to have a brief look at `grails-app/conf` and `test/integration` in the plugin's installation folder.

Comment: Also, this plugin uses floating point numbers for representing monetary amounts.  This causes rounding errors in lots of common cases; I'd probably avoid this plugin and just reimplement the domain objects.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at the files in the zip folder, and copied the domain classes, and that worked. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like ataylor says, don't use this plugin, it's broken. Instead use JScience. Checkout: [Best practice to represent Money (value + currency) in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637389/best-practice-to-represent-money-value-currency-in-grails/5536720#5536720)