# Video Conferencing API for Java

Tags: java, video-conferencing

are there any Free video conferencing APIs for Java...? It's for a telemedicine project. I have to communicate from Java application(Patient's end) to a web client at the doctor's end.

Comment: you should take a look at http://developer.skype.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for specific programming questions (as opposed to tool recommendations). Please familiarize yourself with the [SO Help file](stackoverflow.com/help) for more details. On a side note, a quick Google search would have led you to JMF and libjitsi.

Comment: @MarsAtomic which SE site is more appropriate? Programmers? This is programming related as the API is used in a programming context so it is not just a software tool.

Comment: @JamesPoulson The question, as phrased, isn't a programming question at all, which is what SO is geared towards answering. OP was quite clearly fishing for an API as a resource, as opposed to asking "how do I achieve X using this API." SO's focus is, for better or worse, quite narrowly focused on answers to specific programming questions rather than on resource recommendations. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JamesPoulson I seem to have completely missed the point of your question... Programmers doesn't seem appropriate because it's like SO for conceptual issues rather than specific programming issues. Recommendation question seem more appropriate for more free-wheeling forums like Railsforum or one of the Rails mailing lists.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I understand the policy has changed since I first registered.

It is good of you to give alternatives and perhaps there should be a list.

Beyond that, there is a seeming fine line.

As an example, what difference is there between this question and the following?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app

There is an obvious one in terms of substance or context but this has not stopped the recommendation of APIs.

So can one say that this is left to the better judgement of the community?

Answer (score 7):

[jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) is an open source XMPP client (among other things) thats written mostly in Java and supports video calls. i suggest you start by looking at their source code.

Comment: Is it a client connecting to there server or we can host server side too ?

Answer (score 1):

Try lti-civil library. It will do the work for capturing images from webcam. Rest is on you to process it and use. Here is the link http://sourceforge.net/projects/lti-civil/