# How to compare String representations of doubles if it ends in .00

Tags: java, android, sqlite, testing, android-sqlite

I am currently writing test cases for a ContentProvider in my application (which is a checkbook recording app) and I am having a test fail when it is comparing double values. The best way to illustrate this is with code. I have this function that returns ContentValues for an account object to be inserted into the database:

```
private ContentValues getAccountContentValues(){
   String testName = "Capital One";
   double testStartingBalance = 3000.00;

   ContentValues accountValues = new ContentValues();
   accountValues.put(AccountEntry.COLUMN_NAME, testName);
   accountValues.put(AccountEntry.COLUMN_BALANCE, testStartingBalance);

   return accountValues;
}
```

Inside a function `testInsertReadProvider()` I have the following code, to insert that account:

```
// Get Account values and write them
ContentValues accountValues = getAccountContentValues();
Uri accountInsertUri = 
        mContext.getContentResolver().insert(AccountEntry.CONTENT_URI, accountValues);
long accountRowId = ContentUris.parseId(accountInsertUri);

// Verify we got a row back
assertTrue(accountRowId > 0);

// A cursor is the primary interface to the query results
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        AccountEntry.CONTENT_URI, // Table name
        null, // columns to be returned. Null returns all columns
        null, // Columns for where clause
        null, // Values for where clause
        null // Sort order
);

// Validate the information read from the database.
validateCursor(cursor, accountValues);
cursor.close();
```

The validate cursor function takes a cursor and a ContentValues and loops through them using a map to compare each value. This is a strategy I learned from following a Udacity tutorial on creating Android applications, so maybe there is a better way to compare them instead of as strings, but it looks like this:

```
void validateCursor(Cursor valueCursor, ContentValues expectedValues){
   assertTrue(valueCursor.moveToFirst());

   Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> valueSet = expectedValues.valueSet();

   for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : valueSet){
       String columnName = entry.getKey();
       int idx = valueCursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
       assertFalse(idx == -1);
       String expectedValue = entry.getValue().toString();
       assertEquals(expectedValue, valueCursor.getString(idx));
   }
   valueCursor.close();
}
```

The test is failing when the `assertEquals()` line is called, and I get the following error message:

> junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<3000[.0]> but
>   was:<3000[]>

It looks like the cursor.getString() method is truncating the decimal places if they are equal to 0. If I try this test using a value of 3000.01 it works fine. Is SQLite responsible for dropping the unnecessary zeroes? Can I change the `assertEquals()` in some way so that those two values are treated the same?

Comment: Isn't it a better practice to avoid doubles for currency, due to problems like this as well as floating point accuracy errors?

Comment: @cantido what is an alternative?

Comment: Java has a `Currency` class, there is also Joda-Money. This question addresses representing money: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app

Comment: @cantido if I use the currency class, what will I store it as in the database? Text?

Comment: Both classes adhere to the [ISO 4217 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) for representing amounts, so you would probably be storing them as text in that format

Comment: @cantido thanks. I'll definitely look into this (probably tomorrow, nearing on 1 AM for me) and I'll let you know if I switch over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you really feel like comparing strings, than you will have to hack it a little bit, but there is an alternative below.

First, here's the **TL;DR;** code:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : valueSet){
        String columnName = entry.getKey();
        int idx = valueCursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
        assertFalse(idx == -1);
        String expectedValue = entry.getValue().toString();
        if((Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT == valueCursor.getType(idx))
                && valueCursor.getDouble(idx) % 1 == 0){
            assertEquals(expectedValue, valueCursor.getString(idx) + ".0");
        } else {
            assertEquals(expectedValue, valueCursor.getString(idx));
        }
    }
```

What is probably happening is that each instance of your `double` is at the end being projected to `String` by a different `toString()` method. That's what causing the irregularities.

You can either hack it as I outlined above or do the comparison in a switch statement specifically designed for each type *(IMHO a better solution)*.

Here is the **Switch** version:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : valueSet){
    String columnName = entry.getKey();
    int idx = valueCursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    assertFalse(idx == -1);
    switch(valueCursor.getType(idx)) {
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
            assertEquals(entry.getValue(), valueCursor.getDouble(idx));
            break;
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
            //assertEquals(entry.getValue(), valueCursor.getInt(idx)); // didn't work
            //assertTrue((new Integer((int)entry.getValue())).equals(valueCursor.getInt(idx)));
            assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().toString()), valueCursor.getInt(idx));
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
            assertEquals(entry.getValue(), valueCursor.getString(idx));
            break;
        default:
            assertEquals(entry.getValue().toString(), valueCursor.getString(idx));
    }
}
```

Comment: After some testing: It's the valueCursor.getString(idx) that is being truncated, so *that's* the field I have to add .00 to. And, after testing, I only have to add ".0", because even Double.toString() changes it to "3000.0". I think you're right that the switch statement will be better. Is it best to preform the switch based on `columnName`, since I know which columns correspond to each type?

Comment: I'd probably switch on row type, then no matter how many columns you have you already have a test in place for any possible value. I'll add that variant to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should transfer them to doubles using

`double d1 = Double.parseDouble(text)
 double d2 = Double.parseDouble(text2)`

Do the same for second string and compare results. You can also use abs to be sure there is no difference because of representation:

`assertTrue(Math.abs(d1 -d2) < 0.00001);`

EDIT:

I would go for something like this:

```
try
{
   double d1 = Double.parseDouble(text);
   double d2 = Double.parseDouble(text2);
   assertTrue(Math.abs(d1-d2) < 0.00001);

}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    assertEquals(text, text2);
}
```

Comment: If I do this, it will require a complete reworking of the `validateCursor()` function, because it's not always comparing doubles. Sometimes they're strings, or integers, which is why that function just converts everything back to strings for simplicity. I believe what you're saying will work, I was just hoping there would be a way to ensure the comparison between strings worked.

Comment: But double can hołd integer value, so if you have string="123" it will work too

Comment: But what is the column holds string? I can't call `Double.parseDouble()` on an alpha string, right?

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to write a case statement that checks the columns being compared, and I can group them into their various types and compare them that way, but as I add more columns and more tables that method could get *really* bulky.

Comment: The generic solution wont work in this case. Like you said you will have to check for columns that you are checking. It wont be too bulky I suppose. The problem will only be for floats and doubles. You just need a flag to check that and then an additional assert for that case.

Comment: Check my edit, should work for numbers, and the rest.

Comment: @happyHelper that was a good point, I thought I'd have three `case` blocks inside of a switch but I would only need two. One that handles doubles/floats, and the rest can fall into what I have now.

Comment: I suppose that still doesn't make sense why string comparison doesn't work. It works for 3000.01 but it doesn't work for something .00.