# Cash Register Change Issue

Tags: java

The below code is not calculating the best way to distribute change in a Java 'cash register'. How do I fix it?

```
public void generateUSDChange(){
    change = payment-purchase;
    quarters = (int) (change/.25);
    change -= (quarters * .25);
    dimes = (int) (change/.1);
    change -= (dimes * .1);
    nickels = (int) (change/.05);
    change -= (nickels * .05);
    pennies = (int) (change/.01);
    changeamount = quarters*.25 + dimes*.1 + nickels*.05 + pennies*.01;
    if(changeamount != (payment-purchase)){
        pennies++;
        if(pennies>=5){
            nickels++;
            pennies-=5;
        }
        if(nickels>=2){
            dimes++;
            nickels-=2;
        }
        if(((dimes*.1) + (nickels*.05)) >= .25){
            quarters++;
            dimes-=2;
            nickels--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current and what the desired output ?

Comment: What are the datatypes of all your variables?

Comment: If you use floating point to represent currency, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: My guess is you're trying to use floats.  Don't do that; see [what is the best data type for money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app).

Comment: Most likely your problem is that decimals cannot be exactly represented in floats. Thats because decimals as anyone knows it are presented base 10, where floats are based 2. Check out the BigDecimal if you need exact calculations fro a cash register.

Answer (score 0):

As others also suggested double and floats are not good for currency. You can use BigDecimal. Here's the working code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum CurrencyDenomination {

HUNDRED(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)), FIFTY(BigDecimal.valueOf(50)), TWENTY(BigDecimal.valueOf(20)), 
        TEN(BigDecimal.valueOf(10)), FIVE(BigDecimal.valueOf(5)), ONE(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)), 
                QUARTER(BigDecimal.valueOf(.25)), DIME(BigDecimal.valueOf(.10)), 
                        NICLE(BigDecimal.valueOf(.05)), PENNIES(BigDecimal.valueOf(.01));

private BigDecimal value;

CurrencyDenomination(BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static Map<CurrencyDenomination, Integer> calculate(BigDecimal balance) {
    Map<CurrencyDenomination, Integer> balanceCurrency = new LinkedHashMap<CurrencyDenomination, Integer>();
    BigDecimal leftOver = balance;
    System.out.println("Given amount : "+balance);
    for (CurrencyDenomination currencyDenomination : CurrencyDenomination
            .values()) {

        int count = leftOver.divide(currencyDenomination.value).intValue();

        if (leftOver != BigDecimal.ZERO) {
            if (balanceCurrency.containsKey(currencyDenomination)) {
                int existingCount = balanceCurrency
                        .get(currencyDenomination);
                existingCount = existingCount + count;
                balanceCurrency.put(currencyDenomination, existingCount);
            } else {
                balanceCurrency.put(currencyDenomination, count);
            }
        }

        leftOver = leftOver.remainder(currencyDenomination.value);

        if (leftOver.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return balanceCurrency;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("BalanceCurrency : "+calculate(BigDecimal.valueOf(49.52)));
}
}
```

> Output:

```
Given amount : 49.52
BalanceCurrency : {HUNDRED=0, FIFTY=0, TWENTY=2, TEN=0, FIVE=1, ONE=4, QUARTER=2, DIME=0, NICLE=0, PENNIES=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer and comment about using BigDecimal. Another way to handle it would be to use integer values that represent cents, assuming you are using USD currency. You could try something like this. (The currency amounts are just examples for easy testing)

```
public void generateUSDChange(){
int payment = 500; //$5.00
int purchase = 268; //$2.68
int change = payment - purchase;
int quarters = change / 25;
change = change % 25;
int dimes = change / 10;
change = change % 10;
int nickles = change / 5;
int pennies = change % 5;
System.out.println("Your change is " + quarters + " quarters " + dimes + " dimes " + nickles + " nickles, and "+ pennies + " pennies.");
int change = pennies * 1 + nickles * 5 + dimes * 10 + quarters * 25;
System.out.printf("Your change totals to $%d.%02d", change/100, change%100);}
```