# How to extract data from a JSON array to variables and pass variables to a PHP function

Tags: java, php, arrays, json

I have a Java Program that sends a HTTP POST request to a PHP file. I need the PHP script to extract the JSON data to some variables and call a PHP function with those variables (parameters). Please find the PHP code below.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        var_export($data);      
    }
    else
    {
        var_export($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    }
?>
```

The JSON Object created in Java

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "Dash");
json.put("num", new Integer(100));
json.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
```

Please help me understand how to extract the JSON array data to variables And how to make the call.

Comment: What is your code doing right now?

Comment: It is returning the JSON array to Java Program. I want the PHP script to make a call to a PHP function.

Comment: What's wrong with calling the function? `callWhateverFunction($data);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Answer (score 0):

Once you've run json_decode(), $data is just a "normal" php array with "normal" php values in it.
So, e.g.

```
/*
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "Dash");
json.put("num", new Integer(100));
json.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
=>
*/
// $input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$input = '{"name":"Dash","num":100,"balance":1000.21}';

$data = json_decode($input, true);
$response = array(
    'name_rev'      => strrev($data['name']),
    'num_mod_17'    => $data['num'] % 17,
    'balance_mul_2' => $data['balance'] * 2
);
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // you might want to get rid off JSON_PRETTY_PRINT in production code
```

prints

```
{
    "name_rev": "hsaD",
    "num_mod_17": 15,
    "balance_mul_2": 2000.42
}
```

two more tips:

- You should test whether $data contains all the elements you expect, before accessing them, see http://docs.php.net/isset , http://docs.php.net/filter et al
- a java `Double()` called `balance`. A java double is a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. And you might hit at one point (if not the range than) the precision limit, see [What is the best data type to use for money in java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app)

Comment: Thanks for taking at look at this. This answer is helpful. Thank you..!