# JSR354 (Java Money API) remaining as javax.money or moving to java.money?

Tags: java-money, jsr354

Now that the transfer ballot has taken place and jsr354-api (Java Money API) is set for inclusion in the Java distribution, will its package remain as javax.money or move to java.money?

Is the intention of this `module-info.java` file to allow java.money to be used as an alias?
https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/blob/master/src/main/java/java/money/module-info.java

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998955/javas-monetary-and-currency-operation-jsr-354/53181704

Answer (score 0):

As a module it already is declared as "java.money" but it won't be a mandatory part of the JDK, also see this related question: [Java's Monetary and Currency Operation - JSR 354](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998955/javas-monetary-and-currency-operation-jsr-354/53181704)