# How would I make a double value have a trailing zero in java. My program deals with currency

Tags: java

How would I make a double value have a trailing zero in java. My program deals with currency.
Ex. How do I to make 9.5 to 9.50?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/153724/10504469 might help you.

Comment: a `double` doesn't know the concept of a decimal, as it uses binary fractions and doesn't maintain the precision of its fraction. You can however format it to a particular decimal representation as the answers have shown. The alternative is `BigDecimal` which does represent decimal fractions and keeps a precision too. But BigDecimal arithmetic is slower than `double` and takes more memory.

Comment: See also [What is the best data type to use for money in Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8148684/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

For currencies, it would be better to use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) class which doesn't lose precision. You can define the precision as `scale` parameter.

If you want to display 9.50 to the user, use

```
String.format("%.2f", decimalValue)
```

where 2 is the number of decimal places you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to convert a double to a String with two decimal places, you have to use a DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); 
double doubleValue = 9.5d;
String stringValue = df.format(doubleValue); // "9.50"
```

But when you are dealing with currency, it's better to deal with integers/longs/BigIntegers of the lowest possible amount (1 cent, 1 satoshi, etc) to avoid floating point errors, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a currency, use the currency and internationalisation features of Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double iii = 9.5;

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormat formatUS = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

    System.out.println("Format currency (default) : " + format.format(iii));
    System.out.println("Format currency (Germany) : " + formatUS.format(iii));

}
```

This produces:

```
Format currency (default) : $9.50
Format currency (Germany) : 9,50 €
```