# BigDecimal rounding mode for 2 decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Using BigDecimal what is the mode I should use for the below condition to round up to decimal point ?

If >= USD 0.005 rounds up to USD 0.01, If the amount is < USD 0.005 round down to 0.00.

Should I use `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`?

Comment: aaaand what if `amount  == 0.005`? (also, why `0.004` should become `0.01` but `0.006` should become `0.00`, shouldn't it be the opposite?)

Comment: Don't use big decimal for currency. Use an integer value of cents.

Comment: @Michael: That approach can work, but some currencies (Tunisian Dinar) have 1000 small things in the big thing. And Bitcoin has 8 decimal places. And some don't have a little thing at all (Japanese Yen). A BigDecimal could therefore be the right thing to use.

Comment: @Bathsheba "USD". It doesn't matter how many small units are in a larger unit. Store Dinar as millims. Convert it later.

Comment: All the predefined rounding modes account for all possible values as input, and round to some definitely of "nearest". Your mode does neither as currently written, do you need to work that out before asking a question.

Comment: @Michael I took that to be an example. Sill, it won't be the last USD-only system ever built ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba. A big decimal is still not the right thing to use. Even if the small unit is 1e-6 of the big unit, you should use integers because there are no fractional small units

Comment: @Alvin. Please edit your question

Comment: @MadPhysicist: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java. Although I don't think I should disclose what I use in C++ as my money type ;-)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't use integer because I am calculating using percentage.

Comment: @Alvin. What's that got to do with anything? Do you allow fractional cents? If not, use integers to store the values, or Currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to round < 0.005 to 0.00 and > 0.005 to 0.01.

```
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.004999);
 bd =  bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```