# How to multiply key * value in Map in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this class:

```
class Product {
    public double price;

    public Product(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And a Map:

```
Map<Product, Integer> products = new HashMap<>();
```

That contains several products added like so:

```
products.put(new Product(2.99), 2);
products.put(new Product(1.99), 4);
```

And I want to calculate the sum of all products multiple the values using streams? I tried:

```
double total = products.entrySet().stream().mapToDouble((k, v) -> k.getKey().price * v.getValue()).sum();
```

But it doesn't compile, I get “*Cannot resolve method `getValue()`*”.

I expect:

```
(2.99 * 2) + (1.99 * 4) = 5.98 + 7.96 = 13.94
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a stream instead of a counting variable that you update by looping over your map's `.values()`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My goal is using streams and not regular for each loop. Thanks

Comment: That's fine, but then please explain in your post why that is, because if the _goal_ is to get the sum, there's not really any reason to use streams.

Comment: @JoanP. Don't use floating number types like `double` for money value. These can lead to unexpected calculation results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: `1.99 * 4 = 7.96` but not `3.98`!

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Oh, sorry about that. You're right. Just edited my question.

Comment: @JoanP. Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: @Progman Cannot resolve method getValue().

Comment: @JoanP. Are you looking for `k.getValue()`?

Comment: In your lambda, k is already the key and v already the value. That's why it doesn't compile k.getKey() (you're not handling a Map.Entry, you're already handling the key)

Comment: @Progman Really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream of entries needs single parameter lambda for each entry, not `(k,v)`:

```
double total = products.entrySet().stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.getKey().price * e.getValue()).sum();
```

Comment: It worked as expected, thanks. Also voted-up.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the explicit creation of a `doubleStream` with something like:

```java
double total = products.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(e -> e.getKey().price * e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. Voted-up.

Comment: But why is “the explicit creation of a `doubleStream`” something to avoid?

Comment: @Holger Greater efficiency by combining two steps into one isn't enough reason?

Comment: The appearance in source code does not determine what the Stream implementation does. Both approaches perform exactly the same steps, in the same order. But if there’s ever any performance difference for this use case, the dedicated `sum` method is likely to be faster than the generic `collect` operation.

Comment: @Holger The implementation for `DoubleStream.sum()` uses the same algorithm as `Collectors.summingDouble()`, yup, down to the point of the former creating objects passed to `collect()` to do the work.  The latter just calls a mapping function then instead of making a new stream using it first, which means fewer steps. One less pipeline object in the chain to pull data from. Now, I'll grant you it's not likely to be notably more efficient, but from the code it looks like it will definitely save a few function calls for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question, but I wouldn't use a map for what you are doing. Instead create a new class

```
public class ProductAmount {
    private Product product;
    private int amount;

    public ProductAmount(Product product, int amount) {
        this.product = product;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getCombinedPrice() {
        return product.price * amount;
    }
}
```

Then you can use a `List` instead of a `Map`.

```
List<ProductAmount> products = Arrays.asList(
        new ProductAmount(new Product(2.99), 2),
        new ProductAmount (new Product(1.99), 4)); 
  
products.stream().mapToDouble(ProductAmount::getCombinedPrice).sum();
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. Voted-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like so.

```
double sum = 0;
for(Entry<Product, Integer> e : products.entrySet()) {
    sum += e.getKey().price * e.getValue();
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
13.940000000000001
```

But you have a fundamental flaw in your class.  You don't override `equals` or `hashCode`. So you're are you using the object reference as the key.  Try doing the following:

```
System.out.println(products.get(new Product(1.99));
```

It will print `null` since there is no entry for that reference (it's a different object than the one used to store the value 4).

And finally you should make certain your keys are immutable. Otherwise, circumstances could result in the same error.

Check out [why do I need to override hashcode and equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java).
And since it was mentioned in the comments, also check out [what data type to use for money in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java/8148773#8148773).